# How to synchronize backend timer with mobile app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, timer

I am developing a app that chooses a user and has a 15 sec. timer for that user to respond.   The user app queries the db every 5 sec to see if that user is chosen.  If so The mobile app begins a 15 sec. timer.  The problem is that the timers will never match up because the user app can be on a different timer cycle that the backend and can query the db at a later time.   I use Angular, NodeJS, and expressJS + MongoDB to develop this app.

any suggestion on how I can get the timers to be synchronized?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create API for requesting current server time and use that server time as basis of your timer.

You also need to take into account condition when browser pauses javascript execution. This is true for mobile device. When mobile device is paused/sleep, browser stops javascript execution causing timer not sync anymore.

Every tick, check last tick millisecond with current tick millisecond. If difference is greater than some threshold value then assume timer not sync anymore and need to be sync by requesting current server time and recalculate timer value

Comment: The thing i forgot to mention is that the timer in the backend can start at anytime.  what I mean is that the timer only goes off when certain conditions are met so it can go off at anytime and stop when the conditions are met.  so grabbing the current server time wouldn't allow me to know where the backend timer is currently at